# How can i convert this model to a valid RealmObject?

Tags: java, android, realm

I'm pretty new to *Realm* and i'd like to persist the following model:

```
public class ChangeEntry {

    private int id;
    private long time;
    private boolean active;
    private Set<Change> changes;

    // getters and setters
}
```

`Change` is an `interface` (which i have multiple implementations for):

```
public interface Change {

    void performChange();
}
```

As i understand *Realm* does not support `Set`, so i carried out the following changes:

- switched from `Set<Change>` to `RealmList<Change>`
- made `ChangeEntry` extend `RealmObject`
- made `Change` extend `RealmModel`

Now when i try to save a `ChangeEntry` to *Realm*, i get the following error:

> Only concrete Realm classes are allowed in RealmLists. Neither
>   interfaces nor abstract classes are allowed.

Which is quite self-explanatory.

Is it possible to save this model to *Realm* and preserve the polymorphism that the `Change` interface provides? If so, how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Inheritance/polymorphism is supported only if you manually create a concrete RealmObject that works via single-table inheritance (you use the same object to model all sub-types)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to save this model to Realm and preserve the polymorphism that the Change interface provides?

Currently no, as realm does not yet support polymorphism. It is being worked on though, and you can track the progress [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/761).

For now you have to use only concrete classes.

Comment: That's really sad. Thanks.